# Loginview Before TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Instantly present the LoginViewController in my appdelegate before my tabbarcontroller

> i tried with this code block and also name the navagation controller Identity to "log"

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *logincontroller=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"log"];
[tabBarController presentViewController:logincontroller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Please any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `self.window.rootViewController` when you are in `appDelegate`:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *logincontroller= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"log"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:logincontroller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I dont think you see what I am trying to point out, You are using `UINavigationController`, but the **`UINavigationController`** class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. You are trying to present the login view modally so it is not part of the navigation stack.

You should be looking for **`LoginViewController`** and create a new instance of it using its storyboard Id.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to present the LoginViewcontroller in applicationDidFinishLaunching:? At that point, the root view controller has not appeared yet, so it is not yet in the window hierarchy. There are three things you can do. One, make it appear in the applicationDidBecomeActive:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationForLog"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or, you can make it appear from the tabbar controller's viewDidAppear. This assumes you have a custom tab bar controller.

In MyCustomTabBarController.m:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationForLog"];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Both of these solutions will display the root view controller first, then modally push the log viewcontroller. If you want it to appear immediately, change the animated:YES to animated:NO.

Another way you can do it is to have your login be a root view controller. You shouldn't have a tabbar controller if your user hasn't logged in yet, because then it may try to load content that isn't available. If that's the case, you should start with a single login controller in your storyboard. If login succeeds, you can either put the tabbar on top of the login (instead of the login on top of the tabbar) or you can replace the rootviewcontroller with the login controller.

Edit 1:

When you present a modal view controller on top of another one, in order for the new controller to have a navigation controller, you have to present a navigation controller along with it. This is the storyboard you should have. The first view is your tab controller. When you determine that the user needs to login, preset the UINavigationController whose rootViewController is your loginController.

[image]

Edit 2:

I adjusted my storyboard so the login controller doesn't get covered by the navigation bar. You have to unset Extended Edges: Under Top Bars in the right pane. Also, you can add a back/close button directly onto the navigation bar in storyboard.

[image]

Edit 3:

Note that the controller you should present in the applicationDidBecomeActive: is the navigation controller. The example login controller i showed does nothing, and you should add other functionality to the buttons, etc. When you instantiate and show the navigation controller, it will display whatever rootViewController it has (in this case, your login controller) along with a navigation bar.

Comment: the first solution worked however it doesnt show my navigation bar controller

Comment: yea, the reason is that the navigation controller belongs to the login controller, and after the login completes, there's no navigation controller in your new stack.

Comment: sorry i don't really understand what you are saying @mintrenegade

Comment: so when i pressed Login what line of code should i used to show the TABBARCONTROLLER @mintrenegade

Comment: @m34 I updated the code. In edit 3, i specify that you should instantiate the navigation controller instead of the login controller. So add a storyboard id to the navigation controller, and don't use the "log" storyboard id.